# Block Level Elements in <a> Tag, Validation vs Usability

Tags: html, css, validation, usability

I have often wrapped block level elements with `<a>` tags in order to make the whole group clickable. For example, say I have a list of events:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
            <div style="float: left; display: inline;">12/12/2010</div>
            <div style="float: left; display: inline;">Some event information</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- etc... -->
</ul>
```

**NOTE**: inline styles applied for example only.

This way, the whole thing is clickable rather than only the text within the elements.

Ofcourse, the (x)html validator at [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org) doesn't like this because I've placed a block level element (`<div>`) insider an inline level element (`<a>`). Even though, I am using CSS to define the `<a>` tags as block level, and the `<div>` tags as inline.

I've always coded by the rule of thumb that you should always strive to author valid code; *however*, if your code doesn't validate, and *you understand why it doesn't validate*, and *you have a valid reason for it not validating*, then don't worry about it.

So my question is tri-fold:

1. Is this a *valid* reason for this not to validate?
2. Is the usability gain (by having a larger clickable area) worth it not validating?
3. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to simply use an inline element like `span' inside the anchor element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `span` as below is perfectly valid and you can achieve the same effect.

```
<a href="#" style="display: block;">
    <span style="float: left;">12/12/2010</span>
    <span style="float: left;">Some event information</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Adding display: inline; helps to prevent some css bugs in older versions of IE - http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Comment: I wasn't aware of `float` implicitly setting an element to `display: block;` Now, a new concern with this solution, I've always understood that I should add `display: inline;` to any floated element to prevent IE double margin bugs, does this solution interfere with that bug solution?

Comment: Keep your display: inline.  The floats will still work the same as they do without that extra rule.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `<span>` instead of `<div>` and then apply the same styling.  That way you get the best of all worlds. You can still have your larger click targets, but it will also validate.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your three questions:

1. Not worth the energy to argue.
2. Not if you can find a better way.
3. Use `<span>` tags instead of divs (really, what is to be gained by making a div `display:inline`?); or use Javascript and add an onclick event to the containing `<li>`.

Comment: First, this post really isn't helpful at all: you've effectively said absolutely nothing. Second, the reason I set the div to `display: inline;` is to fix the IE double margin bug on floated elements.

Comment: @jordanstephens: If you read a little closer, you'll see I said to use real inline elements instead of block elements that have been twisted into becoming inline. That way you don't need to float them. Your code took something simple and wrestled it into something complicated. You wouldn't have had to worry about an IE double margin bug if you hadn't done that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my opinion, yes. However, you're pretty much on your own if you decide to disregard validation.
2. Benefits to the user win over benefits to the author, certainly.
3. Use HTML5, where `<a>` elements are allowed to wrap block level elements.

Comment: in regards to point #3, I wasn't aware of this change. I don't think I'm comfortable switching to HTML5 just yet; but that's one more thing to look forward to!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding an onclick event to the div, ie onclick="window.location='redirectpage.html'"> and then the style cursor:pointer.  Works like a charm and also validates.